# Function in status bar

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have formatting for the status bar in my .emacs file:

```
(setq-default    mode-line-format
         '("" mode-line-modified "" 
           mode-line-buffer-identification "-" 
           global-mode-string "" 
           "[" mode-name "." mode-line-process "." minor-mode-alist "" "%n" "]" 
           line-number-mode   "-" "L%l" 
           column-number-mode "-" "C%c" 
           "-" "%P" "-"
           abbreviated-file-name 
           "%-"
           )
         )
```

I am also using the following to show function name in the status bar:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 
  (lambda ()
    (which-function-mode t)))
```

Unfortunately, Both of these snippets can't coexist.
If I keep the first formatting then I wont be able to see the function name.

Is there a way to re-write the above to have both the formatting and the function name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore `mode-line-misc-info` to your mode line format.

In general I would be very wary of *removing* data from the mode line, unless targeting *very specific* pieces of data.

i.e. If you still wish to specify `global-mode-string` explicitly, then remove that from `mode-line-misc-info` rather than removing `mode-line-misc-info` from the mode line!

*Edit:* the above is relevant to Emacs 24; see comments regarding previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response phils.
Could you please elaborate on what I need to do?
Should I add "mode-line-misc-info" to the end of my mode-line-format code?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to replace `global-mode-string` with `mode-line-misc-info` (as the latter contains the former, as well as being the container used by `which-function-mode`. I think you should probably review the default `mode-line-format` compared to your custom one, and make certain that you're not leaving out other useful components.

Comment: That worked on emacs 24.3.1
However, when trying an older emacs (23.3.1) still no function name.
Will google "mode-line-misc-info" to see if it was renamed in newer emacs releases.

Comment: In Emacs 23.3.1 it looks like the `which-function-mode` support is included directly in the default `mode-line-format`. The whole mode line was evidently made more modular for Emacs 24, and `mode-line-misc-info` (and others) do not exist in the previous versions. You may wish to include the following component in your Emacs 23 mode line format: `(which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " "))`.